# $this->load->view() Vs include in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Is there any problem in using a normal include function to include a view in 
codeigniter rather than using $this->load->view() ?**

On of the obvious advt. when using include i think is that there is no need to pass data to the view in the form of an array.
So instead of doing:

```
$data['text'] = 'This is home page';
$this->load->view('home',$data);
```

i can just do:

```
$text = 'This is home page';
include APPPATH. 'views/home.php';
```

Comment: Why use a framework if you're not going to use the basic tools it offers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at the CORE library to understand what does `view()` method do. Some of advantages why use it instead of `include`. Basicly it also include file, but first it checks paths, if file exist, debugging features, logging errors also with 2nd and 3rd option you can return the file content instead of simply print out. Frameworks is for make programming more structured and less effort.